# How do I import a CSV file into my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

I need to import a CSV file in to my app. How can i do that. Is that possible in iPhone?

Thanks,

Comment: "Is that possible" - sure, by writing code....

Comment: how can i browse through files in iPhone.

Comment: Where is the file located? Web, built into your program, somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

You can try Matt Gallagher's [CSVParser](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try CHCSVParser.  [CHCSVParser tutorial](http://caydenliew.com/2011/11/parsing-csv-to-objective-c-with-chcsvparser/)